# Open images and links in a new tab instead of the current

Tags: feature-request

Images and links in questions and answers open in the current tab, redirecting away from SE. With use of the browser back-button you end up where you were, including the position you scrolled to, though I suggest opening all links in a new tab.

Comment: Dupe on uber-meta: [Make links posted by users open in a new window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2275/241919), which has been officially declined by Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the link will bring up a list which includes "open in a new tab". This gives you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this depend on your browser settings? Because for me, any link I click, it opens a new tab. (I'm using firefox)